# How do I enable birthday reminders or view birthdays as events in Calendar on Nexus 4

Tags: contacts, nexus-4, people-app

Simple problem: I forget the birthdays of my friends. I have the dates saved in my contacts (CardDAV-Sync address book) and can view them with the People app. I have not found a way to set up an alert or reminder, though. Alternatively I'd like to see them as events in Calendar. I would hope there is some option in the stock Android 4.3 of my Nexus 4 to configure this, but if it is not possible, do you know of a simple reminder app *that does not ask for full internet access*?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Google Calendar?

Comment: Also, did you look in the Play Store? I see a number of apps which purport to send reminders or otherwise list your contacts birthdays.

Comment: @AlEverett: I'm using the stock Google Calendar _app_ (version 201306302 if that is of any use) but only use my own CalDAV calendar _datasets_ synced with my own Radicale server. I do not display or sync any of the Google calendar _datasets_ (for the lack of a better word).

Comment: @AlEverett: Yes, I've seen those apps but they all suffer from feature creep and thus permission creep. I draw the line at full internet access, because I don't want them to be able to send my personal data to their servers. I've emphasized the passage asking for that in my question.

Answer (score 4):

*..., but if it is not possible, do you know of a simple reminder app that does not ask for full Internet access?*

The topic is also discussed in the [Google forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/OaaO2og9m5w) for the calender application and indeed there seem to be only workarounds.

There is also an app mentioned, which does provide the notifications for the birthdays and does not need Internet access: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.noyer.consulting.contactevents.pro

That is a paid app for a small amount, but there is also a free version with Internet access for advertisements: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.noyer.consulting.contactevents.free

If you just want to try the free version if it works for you, you could perform the following steps:

- Download the free app in the Play Store
- Turn your device into flight mode
- Start the app
- In Android 6 or higher: Grant access to adress book at first start
- Check the app, widget etc. (Notifications are only raised at midnight)
- Uninstall the app
- Turn off flight mode
- Decide if it worth to get the Pro version

Comment: The paid app costs hardly anything—so it makes perfect sense to buy it.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a native way either for that, and was wondering why it worked on one of my devices but not on the others. On the "working" device, I'm using [aCalendar](http://www.appbrain.com/app/acalendar-android-calendar/org.withouthat.acalendar) as a frontend to the Google Calendar, which also comes with a nice widget, and is really handy. *aCalendar* also sends birthday reminders, shows them on the widget itself and also puts a hint in the notification bar which is hard to miss. So until you find a solution you like more, this would be a possibility.

Comment: Thx. It also seems to have reasonable permissions. I'll look into it if there is no other answer.

Comment: Exactly those were my arguments when I chose it for my device: Handy, comfortable, light-weight, and "reasonable permissions" :) Good luck, further; I'll watch this question as I'm curious for "on-board alternatives" as well.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly follow these steps :

1. [How to Add Your Gmail Contacts' Birthdays to Google Calendar](http://email.about.com/od/googlecalendartips/qt/How-To-Add-Your-Gmail-Contacts-Birthdays-To-Google-Calendar.htm?utm_source=google&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=shareurlbuttons)

**Add Your Gmail Contacts' Birthdays to Google Calendar**

To add a calendar showing and alerting you to birthdays of your Gmail contacts to Google Calendar:

- Select Settings | Calendar settings in Google Calendar.
- Go to the Calendars tab.
- Follow the Browse interesting calendars » link under Other Calendars.
- Open the More tab.
- Click Subscribe for Contacts' birthdays and events.

  1. [Sarah Dee's Answer on Why it's not possible to add notifications at Birthday's Calendar?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/OaaO2og9m5w)

Please follow these steps:

- Go to google.com/calendar so you are just viewing the regular home screen
- On the left hand side under Other calendars, find Friends' Birthdays, click the drop down arrow and select Reminders and notifications from the menu
- Under the Event Reminders section, Click Add a reminder, set the desired reminder
- Click Save

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference (please [edit] your question and do so). Otherwise your question ceases to be helpful in case the link dies.

Comment: These guides only work for the Google calendar, unfortunately, and not for other calendar accounts, e.g. the caldav calendar I was referring to in my question. (I have no contact information stored in the Google account.)

Comment: There is not option to set event reminders fot the birthday calendar

Comment: In what reality is this answer even remotely correct?

Comment: This answer was probably correct at the time (2014), but now it is outdated (2018).